# VSTO - Lock all cells of excel worksheet without changing selection

Tags: excel, vsto, selection, cell, locked

I'm developing an application add-in for excel using VSTO, programming in VB.NET. I'm trying to lock (by setting ".locked = true") for all cells in my worksheet, and I'm currently doing it this way:

```
Me.sheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Me.sheet.Cells.Select()
CType(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection, Excel.Range).Locked = True
```

The problem is that I want to do it **without changing the selection**, because it is important to my application.

Any ideas of how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: You don't need to select cells in order to lock them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved!

```
Me.sheet = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Me.sheet.Cells.Locked = True
```

Thank you!

Comment: Second line has some redundancy: you can use  `Me.sheet.Cells.Locked = True`